# setState not updating part of page when called

Tags: flutter, setstate

When accessing a flutter page, I'm creating a graph (syncfusion) and 2 rows with values downloaded from some API.

I create an empty page, then, when the data is loaded, I set the variables with the respective data and call `setState(() {walletRows=wallet.getWallet();});` to update the rows variable with the data for the rows I mentioned in the beginning.

Problem: the graph is actually generated but the rows are not created (if I change page or hot reload, the rows appears)

In initState i call `loadPageData` which loads the data in 2 variables.

```
  @override
  initState() {
    loadPageData();
    _pageController = PageController();

    super.initState();
  }
```

This is the loadPageData func

```
  Future<void> loadPageData() async {
    this._chartData = await getChartData(); // variable to feed sfcartesianchart
    const storage = FlutterSecureStorage(); // getting token for api call
    String token = await storage.read(key: 'token') as String;
    var wallet = WalletRow();
    wallet.addText(token);
    setState(() {walletRows=wallet.getWallet();}); //setting state with updated walletrows

  }
```

Within a Column i have another Column where the children are taken from walletRows.

```
  Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children:  [
        const Text(
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          "Rows",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20,
              color:
                  Color.fromARGB(255, 113, 113, 113)),
        ),

        Column(children:walletRows)
      ]),
```

As requested, here is the page (just part of it, else it would be too long):
https://pastebin.com/cVC2pdhX

**UPDATE**

I realized that if I add a Button with setState on the onPressed event, the rows get correctly added; so it seems there is a problem with the first setState although I still can't find a solution to it.

Comment: Can you share the whole code of the page?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cVC2pdhX

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: Ah! thanks for that tip, didn't know. However, the syncfusion part actually works flawlessly. The problem is with those rows.